# How to minimize an objective function in R using optim which takes a very long time to run

Tags: r, optimization

I have a certain objective function which I am trying to minimize using optim in R (I'm using the L-BFGS-B algorithm). My issue is that if I run this objective function once, it takes about 30 minutes to evaluate. Now when I am using optim to minimize such a function, it is taking forever to converge.
What are my possibilities for reducing this time taken to converge? I truly appreciate any help in this regard.
The following is my objective function:

```
pairwise <- function(x,fixed = c(rep(FALSE,5))){
  params <- fixed
  l_1 <- function(p){
    params[!fixed] <- p
    alpha <- params[1]
    beta_0 <- params[2]
    beta_1 <- params[3]
    beta_2 <- params[4]
    rho <- params[5]
    add_pi <- function(d){
      k <- beta_0+(d[3]*beta_1)+(d[4]*beta_2)
      k1 <- exp(k) ## for Poisson regression
      d <- cbind(d,k1)
    }
    dat_split <- split(x , f  = x$index)
    result <- lapply(dat_split, add_pi)
    
    result <- rbindlist(result)
    result <- as.data.frame(result)
    colnames(result) <- c('index','y','x1','x2','lamb')
    result_split <- split(result, f = result$index)
    
    expression <- function(d){
      bin <- as.data.frame(combn(d$y , 2))
      pr <- as.data.frame(combn(d$lamb , 2))
      
      ## Evaluation of the probabilities:
      f_jk <- function(u,v){
        
        
        dummy_func <- function(x,y){
          ppois(x, lambda = y)
        }
        dummy_func_1 <- function(x,y){
          ppois(x-1, lambda = y)
        }
        
        k <- mapply(dummy_func,u,v)
        k_1 <- mapply(dummy_func_1,u,v)
        inv1 <- inverseCDF(as.matrix(k), pnorm)
        inv2 <- inverseCDF(as.matrix(k_1), pnorm)
        mean <- rep(0,2)
        lower <- inv2
        upper <- inv1
        corr <- diag(2)
        corr[lower.tri(corr)] <- rho
        corr[upper.tri(corr)] <- rho
        prob <- pmvnorm(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = mean, corr = corr)
        prob <- (1+(1/alpha))*(prob^alpha)
        ## First expression: (changes for Poisson regression)
        lam <- as.vector(t(v))
        v1 <- rpois(1000, lambda = lam[1])
        v2 <- rpois(1000, lambda = lam[2])
        all_possib <- as.data.frame(rbind(v1,v2)) 
        new_func <- function(u){
          k <- mapply(dummy_func,u,v)
          k_1 <- mapply(dummy_func_1,u,v)
          inv1_1 <- inverseCDF(as.matrix(k), pnorm)
          inv2_1 <- inverseCDF(as.matrix(k_1), pnorm)
          mean1 <- rep(0,2)
          lower1 <- inv2_1
          upper1 <- inv1_1
          corr1 <- diag(2)
          corr1[lower.tri(corr1)] <- rho
          corr1[upper.tri(corr1)] <- rho
          prob1 <- pmvnorm(lower = lower1, upper = upper1, mean = mean1, corr = corr1)
          prob1 <- prob1^(alpha)
          
        }
        val <- apply(all_possib, 2, new_func)
        val_s <- mean(val)    ## approximation
        
        return(val_s - prob)
      }
      
      
      final_res <- mapply(f_jk, bin, pr)
      
      final_value <- sum(final_res)
    }
    
    u <- sapply(result_split,expression)
    return(sum(u))
  }
}
```

This objective has been run on the following simulated data:

```
  x1 <- rnorm(600,0,1)
  x2 <- rnorm(600,0,1)
  data_2 <- data.frame(x1,x2)
  lin_pred <- 1+(0.1 * data_2[1]) + (-0.3*data_2[2]) 
  prob <- exp(lin_pred) ## for Poisson regression
  index <- rep(1:100, each = 6)
  data <- data.frame(index,prob)
  data_split <- split(data,f=data$index)
  create_y <- function(p){
    
    y <- c()
    y_1 <- rpois(1,p[1,2])
    y <- append(y,y_1)
    for(i in 2:6){
      mu <- p[i,2] - 0.1*p[i-1,2]   ## for d_it
      d <- rpois(1,mu)              ## d_it's
      u <- 0.1*y[i-1] + d           ## consecutive values of y
      y <- append(y,u)
    }
    return(y)
  }
  
  res <- lapply(data_split,create_y)
  y <- data.frame(x=unlist(res))
  final_data <- data.frame(index,y,x1,x2)
  colnames(final_data) <- c("index","y","x1","x2") ## This is the final data frame
```

And lastly I have this code to optimize my above defined objective function:

```
val <- pairwise(final_data, c(1,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
optim(par = c(beta_0 =0.8, beta_1 =0.01 ,beta_2 = -0.01,rho=0.02),fn = val ,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = c(-Inf,-Inf,-Inf,-1),upper = c(Inf,Inf,Inf,1))
```

Comment: The easiest tweak could be to use [optimParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimParallel/index.html) as a drop-in replacement if you have multiple CPUs to work with.

Comment: I do have access to a multicore CPU. I tried running using optimParallel as well but somehow it continued to take a long time. Shall I post that code here?

Comment: I think you are generating random numbers inside your objective. That is usually a recipe for disaster. The objective should be deterministic.

Comment: Yes indeed that's the section that's slowing it down. But I'll have to get that approximation each time. Can't find a way to avoid it.